# Solution to a Find/Replace formatting issue

Tags: microsoft-word

Right now, here's my setup:

Find: <[![! ]@.com>
Replace: ^&.com

However, I'm also trying to start after paragraph breaks (!^13). How do I add that as a secondary requirement for the characters before the .com?

Answer (score 0):

By deduction from what you have written, what you are trying to do is not clear to me (or seems a unlikely requirement) but `^13{1}<[!([! ][!^13]@.com>` might be of some use to you.